# Retrofit and Rxjava not sending request

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I'm trying to implement Retrofit with RxJava. I've got all of the components shown in every tutorial I've found on the topic, but I don't actually see a request ever started. What am I missing? Converting Retrofit to RxJava means there is no `.enqueue()` to call, so why isn't the request sent? The app has the internet permissions and I've tested it on both emulators and physical devices. What can I do to further debug the issue?

```
@GET("things/{thing}")
    fun getThing(@Path("thing") thingName: String): Observable<Thing>
```

```
private val service: ThingsService

init {
    val clientBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    clientBuilder.addInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor())

    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://example.com")
        .client(clientBuilder.build())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava3CallAdapterFactory.create())
        .build()

    service = retrofit.create(ThingsService::class.java)
}

fun test(thingName) {
    val aThing = service.getThing(thingName)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe({ thing -> }, { error -> })
}
```

With this configuration I never see a request logged.

Comment: How do you run test? Do you run it in a Junit-Runner-Thread? It might be the case, that due to threading the method `test` invocation is fall through and the program exits. Can you give us some context regarding how you call test?

Comment: Just a placeholder method name. The actual method is called from UI interaction, and I've verified that the method is actually getting called.

Comment: I can't verify that the retrofit methods are called because there's nowhere to put a debugger, but up to the `service.getThing()` is definitely being called.

Comment: Do you see any error in logcat? It might be the case, that make the http call from the main-tread, which is forbidden in Android, which in turn would throw an error. What will happen, when you add `getThing(t).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io).doOnNext { log stuff out hier }`. Do you see some output in logcat? Also please log out onNext and onError. When you override the onError with nothing, you will not see nothing.

Comment: If I switch back to using standard `Call` objects, yeah, it throws a network on main thread exception, but as shown in the question, no threading seems correct. Nothing is printed to log, no errors, and log statements inside `.subscribe() ` or `.doOnNext()` are never called.

Comment: I didn't test logging in `.onError()`, however even an error would most likely trigger the logging interceptor, which never logs anything.

Comment: I am not that proficient with Retrofit. Is it possible to extract  the networking part to an sample? I would try to dig deeper into Retrofit and try to set some breaking points and go line by line (step into) until I see something interesting.

Answer (score 0):

The issue of seeing absolutely no output was a combination of several problems:

1. While I tested putting a log statement in the `.subscribe()` block, I didn't put one in the error block.
2. The log level on the `HttpLoggingInterceptor` wasn't set correctly to log the type of error occurring.
3. On one of the devices (the emulator) the internet permission hadn't been granted correctly because the permission was added to the manifest file after the first install.

Solution:

Remove and reinstall the app after adding the internet permission, check for content in the error block, and be sure to set the correct log level in the interceptor:

```
val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
   level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
}

val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().apply {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        addInterceptor(interceptor)
    }
}.build()
```